# Embedded Java app crashes, no exception and no apparent reason

Tags: java, embedded, busybox

I have a Java application running on an embedded linux (BusyBox v1.12.4). I am using CDC 1.1 and the version of the VM (cvm) is CDC HI phoneme_advanced-Core-1.1.2-b111.

The application's main purpose is to collect some data and send it via GPRS (using the FTPClient of the Apache commons library)

The application was running fine, and then lately I added the ability to compress a file before sending it. Following is the code that compresses the file:

```java
public static boolean compressFile(String file, String fileCompressed)
{
   boolean result = false;

   try
    {
       Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tar -czvf " + fileCompressed + " " + file);
       System.err.println("Compression in progress");
       int returnValue = process.waitFor();
       System.err.println("Finished compression");
       BufferedReader stderror = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

       String s;

       s = stderror.readLine();
       if (s == null)
       {
          result = true;
       } else
       {
          result = false;
       System.err.println(s);
       }
     } catch (IOException e)
     {
          result = false;
          Log.getInstance().newMessage(e.getMessage(), Log.ERROR);

    } catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
          result = false;
          Log.getInstance().newMessage(e.getMessage(), Log.ERROR);
    }

    return result;
}
```

After adding this function, the application started crashing! The log didn't contain any memory error or exception and the system it's running on lacks correct configuration, so the syslog doesn't show anything as well (the equipment maker told me that it will be available in the upcoming version). I can't even launch the VM in debug mode!

I have to add that the application doesn't crash during the compression, it just crashes randomly during its execution. The thing is that it crashes only when compression is enabled!

Has anybody seen this before? does anybody have an idea on how to debug/solve this?

Comment: You may have changed some uninitialized value in another location within the application by adding that method.  Typically when "unused method or function or variable causes program behavior change" is the problem, the root cause is an uninitialized variable.  The reason is that you were getting lucky before, and that uninitialized variable had a value that was working out for you.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would suspect would be an out-of-memory condition, caused by the execution of the `gzip` compression engine. Try calling `dmesg` in the shell to see if the [kernel OOM killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) sacrificed any processes.

A few other things to try:

- Remove the `v` flag of `tar`: You do not seem to need the extra output and it *might* cause some kind of problem down the road, depending on you exact environment.
- Use `tar` without the `z` option: If the crashes go away with compression disabled, then it's probably a memory issue.
- Try `cat`, one of the the simplest external processes that you could start, instead of `tar` and see what happens.
- Stress-test your hardware: using compression may simply be exposing underlying overheating or data corruption issues that are not normally visible.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by looking at the exit code of the JVM -- that'll tell you if it died from a signal, and if so, which.